# change height of title area in a block in latex beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using latex to create a poster, and I'd like to have a bit more padding around the titles of the blocks. Where is the setting for this?

Here is a minimum working example...
beamerposter_block_height.tex:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{MWE_theme}}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Introduction}
        the rain in spain                    
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

beamerthemeMWE_theme.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeMWE_theme}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=white,fg=black,series=\bfseries,family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=white,bg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\LARGE,series=\bfseries}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=10ex,dp=0.5ex,center,leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}%
    %{\rule[-0.4ex]{0mm}{2ex}\insertblocktitle}%
    {\vskip5ex
     \textbf{\phantom{Gg}\insertblocktitle}% phantom because of baseline problem
     \vskip5ex
    }
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]%[shadow=true]
```

Comment: Could you expand your code to a minimal working example, please? Short comment: `series=\serif` should not be set as a beamer color and I doubt that `\serif` is a valid command, use `\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\LARGE,series=\bfseries,family=\rmfamily}`instead)!

Comment: I was hoping someone just knew the command. I don't really have a problem to debug, I just don't know where to set a variable. Anyway, that's a MWE, and you can hopefully see that the block title looks vertically cramped... Incidentally, the body text still doesn't want to become serif, although your suggestion worked fine for the block title.

Comment: There's a problem with your `beamerthemeMWE_theme.sty` file; the final line `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]%[shadow=true]` overrides some of the settings that appear before; is this intentional or is a mistake?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I guess it's a mistake. I want rounded block corners, but I didn't know that this conflicted with any of the other commands. How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I'm aware of it, I use the [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package which has customisable spacing around the title, and many more settings.

Answer (score 3):

A dirty trick in situations like this is to insert a strut using `\rule`.

```
\begin{block}{\rule[-0.6ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}Introduction}
the rain in spain
\end{block}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. If there isn't a setting for title height, I'll go with the dirty trick.

Comment: as a follow up question... I tried a \rule command within the style file (commented out in the MWE). Why doesn't that work?

Comment: Another question, perhaps a little late: is there any way to hook such a rule onto the definition of `block`?